# What is the [:] doing in this line? table[i] = table[i - coin][:]

Tags: python, dynamic-programming

This is a dynamic programming solution to the minimum change problem in python from [Bryce Boe](https://github.com/bboe/bryceboe.com/blob/master/content/dynamic-programming-coin-change-problem-in-python.md).  I don't understand what's going on in the elif block in general.  More specifically, what is the [:] doing in this line

```
table[i] = table[i - coin][:]
```

Could this be written with a dictionary instead of the table memoization list?

```
def solve_coin_change(coins, value):
    """A dynamic solution to the coin change problem"""

    table = [None for x in range(value + 1)]
    table[0] = []
    for i in range(1, value + 1):
        for coin in coins:
            if coin > i:
                continue
            elif not table[i] or len(table[i - coin]) + 1 < len(table[i]):
                if table[i - coin] != None:
                    table[i] = table[i - coin][:]
                    table[i].append(coin)

    if table[-1] != None:
        print('%d coins: %s' % (len(table[-1]), table[-1]))
    else:
        print('No solution possible')

coins = [1, 2, 4]
value = 11

solve_coin_change(coins, value)
```

Answer (score 3):

This line is making a copy of the list `table[i - coin]`, not an alias. It is using `slice` notation.

```
table[i] = table[i - coin][:]
```

Each element is copied, instead of assigning a new label to `table[i - coin]`, making `table[i]` an independent object; i/e if you can modify either `table[i - coin]`, or `table[i]` independently of the other.

Comment: It's a shallow copy, not a deep copy.

Comment: yes, thank you @chepner

Answer (score 2):

That is the list slicing notation. In this case it is being used to make a copy of table[i - coin], instead of using a reference.